# View newsfeed/timeline for a specific GitHub repository

Tags: github

I'm aware GitHub lets you follow multiple repositories with the following features:

1. Personalized newsfeed of all repos you're watching -- https://github.com
2. Global timeline of all public repos -- https://github.com/timeline

Is there a way to view newsfeed/timeline for a **single** repository?

E.g. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/timeline

The closest solution I found is a browser extension called [GitHub Feed Filter for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-feed-filter/jcpkhafkpnaljjbgdgbehajihicjalkc).

It works by applying a filter on your personalized newsfeed. However, if you're watching many repositories, you'd have to click the "More" button at the bottom of the newsfeed multiple times to get enough stories to feed the filter.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just asked for this feature and they've replied that right now it's only supported on their API: http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events

Comment: Awesome, they finally added it! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Samus_ I had the same question today, and now I am wondering, what is the place for somebody to request github team for a feature? Btw, thanks for the answer and the link.

Comment: I think their "feedback" form is the way to go but according to my sources you need a few similar requests to actually get their attention.

Comment: I think it is helpful to write a concrete example: e.g. for jquery, the feed is https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/events

Answer (score 5):

Commit Feed on per-repo basis exist: https://github.com/username/reponame/commits/master.atom

Comment: I'm actually interested in the newsfeed associated with a repository. Imagine creating a Github account and use it to watch just one repository -- that's what I want. The repo-based newsfeed shows you: push events, comments on issues, new issues, new pull requests, new branches, etc. Those are not available by the commit log.

Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Will test watched repo today, but for forked it works - feed from your own dashboard show all actions in parent repo

Answer (score 3):

I just posted an [answer to this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542346/atom-rss-feeds-on-github-issues/10707384#10707384).

Briefly:

GitHub appears to now support an "everything" feed with the following convention:

```
https://github.com/username.private.actor.atom?token=somehextoken
```

Where `somehextoken` is replaced with a token relevant to your account.

You can get his feed+token URL automatically from GitHub using the following steps:

1. Login to your GitHub account
2. Go to the following page: https://github.com/dashboard/yours
3. Click on the News Feed button with feed—icon in the top right of the page.
4. This will take you to a feed XML page. Copy the URL form your browser and paste where needed.
5. Filter the feed to your needs. The feed itself appears to include Issues updates and other details from all of the repos connected to your account. In my case, I just used a standard text filter to grab just the feed elements with MyAcct/MyRepo1 in their title.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This still suffers the same problem I am having. When you watch many repositories, stories generated by active repos tend to wash away stories from less active repos. Also, if I remember correctly, when you starting watching a repo, only newer stories from that repo show up in your feed.

Comment: The answer above only gives you feed elements from *your* repos. In principle, you could create a new GitHub account, fork only the repo that you want to have in your feed, and then follow the instructions above on this new GH account.  In practice, I have few enough repos of my own on my normal account -- and the feed-titles are consistent-enough -- that it is easy to filter them. If you've forked a lot of repos, then the separate-account idea should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub Android app has such a feature. If you go to a repo, there's a "news" item in the main navigation. It also shows things that you don't see in your personal newsfeed. For example, you see if someone who you don't follow stars the repo.

I find it really useful and it's a shame that the normal website doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score -1):

This is a small and simple jQuery plugin to make github repositories, activity and gists widget.
https://github.com/bachors/jQuery-Github-Feed